# How stop execution of the staging process in KIT DataManager?

Tags: java, oop, exception

I would like to know how to stop the Processor in Staging phase (e.g. [this processor](https://github.com/kit-data-manager/base/blob/master/MetaDataManagement/MDM-Content/src/main/java/edu/kit/dama/mdm/content/mets/MetsMetadataExtractor.java) in  member `performPreTransferProcessing`).

Repo on GitHub: https://github.com/kit-data-manager/base

Not sure how to find out what should be changed to go on with the next Processor (if any).

I imagine something like `Context.status = CONSTANTS.stopped` but lack to find the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by the main contributor of the project … I will answer a bit more excessive still.

> performPreTransferProcessing(TransferTaskContainer pContainer) throws StagingProcessorException;
>   // signature for [AbstractStagingProcessor](https://github.com/kit-data-manager/base/blob/e5fa04576b646a93229d9c53f4d23cd3fc3bcefa/Staging/Client/src/main/java/edu/kit/dama/staging/processor/AbstractStagingProcessor.java)

The exception [StagingProcessorException](https://github.com/kit-data-manager/base/blob/d56dd8bbbbb58faced832bec40d87e90710c1917/Staging/Client/src/main/java/edu/kit/dama/staging/exceptions/StagingProcessorException.java) is located in package

```
import edu.kit.dama.staging.exceptions.StagingProcessorException;
```

and can be raised e.g. simply with a message

```
throw new StagingProcessorException("this ends the processor and renders it unsuccessful");
```

and of course this should only be raised conditionally, e.g. from one of the two pre-processing members.

But:

- data still is first uploaded before the Processor runs
- there is no cleanup swiping it from cache